# How to fix error, when copying a column of filtered list object table into another table?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two list object tables. I want filter the first, select a column there, and then copy the values into a second list object table in another worksheet. I tried it with the macro recorder, but the resulted macro gives me this error: pastespecial method of range class failed.

What do I wrong?

```vb
Sub NewMacro()
'
' NewMacro Macro
'

'

    Sheets("Source").Select
    If ActiveSheet.FilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
    Range("Source[FirstCol]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Source").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, _
         Criteria1:="A"
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Destination").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Destination").Range.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=False
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the code according to your requirement,  It will paste in A1 in Destination sheet. use Offset to remove header

```
  Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim LastRow As Long


    With Worksheets("Source")
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:="A"
         LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
              Destination:=Sheets("Destination").Range("A1")
    End With
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

In this solution the header is copying, I want only the data. And what have I to do, so that the copied data is pasted in the destination list object table as new lines? Actual the data is pasted, but the table doesnt change its range.